# Email validation for specific domains

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I need help in email validation, this validation code all email in specific format like,   test@test.gov.au, test@something.ac.au and i want it to be allowed in format test@something.au

(Note : Here I am only allowed to get entry for 5 domains that is gov.au, edu.au, govt.nz, ac.au and csiro.au)

My code is as follow

JS:

```js
function emailTldValidation(tlds) {
            $.validator.addMethod("emailTld", function(value,element) {
              if (value.search("@") != -1) {
                    return (/(.+)@(.+)\.(gov\.au|edu\.au|ac\.nz|csiro\.au|govt\.nz)$/).test(value);
                    //return (/(.+)@(.+)\.(csiro\.au|gov|gov\.us)$/).test(value);
                }
                return false;
            },"Please enter valid tld like "+tlds); 

            $.validator.addClassRules({
                stringInput: {
                    emailTld: true
                }
            });
        }
```

And the following code is validate in function.php

```php
function validateEmail($email) {
        //validate email here from server side
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            //validate tld
            $validTlds = str_replace(".", "\.", VALID_EMAIL_TLDS);
            $validTlds = "\.".str_replace(",", "|\.", $validTlds);
            $emailArr = explode("@", $email);
            $emailTld = $emailArr[1];
            if (preg_match('/^[-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z][a-z]|('.$validTlds.')\z/', strtolower($emailTld))) {
                //check main domain here
                $exValidTlds = explode(",", VALID_EMAIL_TLDS);
                $exValidTlds = array_map('trim', $exValidTlds);
                foreach($exValidTlds as $tld) {//if exist then
                    if(strstr($emailTld, ".".$tld)) {
                        if($tld == strrchr($emailTld, $tld)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
function validateEmail($email) {
  //validate email here from server side
  if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   //validate tld
   $validTlds = str_replace(".", "\.", VALID_EMAIL_TLDS);
   $validTlds = "\.".str_replace(",", "|\.", $validTlds);

   //$validTlds = str_replace(",", "|\.", $validTlds);
   $emailArr = explode("@", $email);

   $emailTld = $emailArr[1];
   
   if ($emailTld == 'csiro.au')
   {
    //check main domain here
    
    return true;
   
   }
   elseif (preg_match('/^[-a-z0-9]+('.$validTlds.')\z/', strtolower($emailTld))) {
   
   
    //check main domain here
    $exValidTlds = explode(",", VALID_EMAIL_TLDS);
    $exValidTlds = array_map('trim', $exValidTlds);
    foreach($exValidTlds as $tld) {//if exist then

     if(strstr($emailTld, ".".$tld)) {
      if($tld == strrchr($emailTld, $tld)) {
       return true;
      }
     }
    }
    return false;
   }
  }
  return false; 
 }
```

This regexp worked pretty well for me:

```
.+@(?:(?:govt*)|(?:edu)|(?:ac)|(?:csiro))\.(?:au|nz)
```

I used this tool to create it: http://regexpal.com/

FYI, validating email is *incredibly* difficult: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Edit: After re-reading your question, it seemed like you might need validation for emails with subdomains and such as well. This is probably better suited for more open ended domains:

```
.+@(?:\w+\.\w+)
```

Edit 2: So the problem is that your validation is too light for your complexity.

```
.+@(?:(?:.+\.(?:(?:govt*)|(?:edu)|(?:ac))\.(?:au|nz))|(?:csiro\.au))
```

Breaking it down:

```
.+         // Match at least 1 of any character
@          // An @ symbol
(?:        // The group of everything right of the @ symbol
(?:        // The group of domains that have subdomains
.+\.       // At least one character in front of a .
(?:        // govt, edu or ac
\.         // a dot
(?:        // au or nz
(?:        // or simply 'csiro.au'
```

You can't get around the fact that four of your domains need a subdomain, and one does not.

Comment: Thanks @dclowd9901 : but it is not working for my code...as there is specific constraints that only something@smthng.gov.au or something@smthing.ac.au, or something@smthing.govt.nz or something@smthing.edu.au or something@csiro.au email format will allowed only.  Other all are working fine but it is showing something@csiro.au as a invalid email id.  I need to allow this also.

Comment: Then it's your code, and I can't help you there because everything looks fine.

Comment: Here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ririyeziga/1/

The problem isn't the regexp now. It's gotta be something else.

Comment: thanks @dclowd9901...issue has been solved by using this validation code